# findHomography not working in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

I have been working on an image stitching project using OpenCV 3.0. I use the findHomography function like so:

```
findHomography(imageOnePoints, imageTwoPoints, CV_RANSAC);
```

but when I try to compile my code, I am returned the following error messages:

```
stitch.cpp:111:75: error: ‘CV_RANSAC’ was not declared in this scope
 Mat homographyMatrix = findHomography(imageOnePoints, imageTwoPoints, CV_RANSAC);

stitch.cpp:111:84: error: ‘findHomography’ was not declared in this scope
 Mat homographyMatrix = findHomography(imageOnePoints, imageTwoPoints, CV_RANSAC);
```

I have already declared that I am  using "namespace cv" so I do not need the preceeding "cv::". I am not sure what the problem is. Any advice on these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try just `RANSAC`. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography. If that doesn't work for you, the value is `8`.

Comment: Using just RANSAC didn't work so I changed it to 8, yet the findHomography function still is "not declared in this scope".

Comment: Just to be sure, you did `#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"`, right?

Comment: I didn't, and when I added it everything compiled flawlessly! Well that fixed it. Thank you so much! How do I declare this post answered?

Comment: I'll go ahead and type up a quick answer, and then you can accept it in a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the header file for `findHomography` was missing:

```
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest OpenCV version, CV_RANSAC is renamed to RANSAC.

just use `H = findHomography(ref, tst, RANSAC)`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. `CV_RANSAC` was not declared.

Solution: `CV_RANSAC` => `RANSAC`

Q2. `findHomography` was not declared.

Solution: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` would be enough for most cases.

For this specific question you can also use `#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>`